# Read String Length in C - Cannot use <string.h>

Tags: c, string

How can I determine how many characters are in a string? 
The problem I face is the stipulation that I cannot use the `<string.h>` library.

Here is what I'm trying to solve:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 1024

int string_length(char *string);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    assert(string_length("") == 0);
    assert(string_length("!") == 1);
    assert(string_length("Hello, world!") == 13);
    assert(string_length("17... seventeen.\n") == 17);

    printf("All tests passed.  You are awesome!\n");

    return 0;
}

int string_length(char *string) {
    // Add code here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is encoded an end of string?

Comment: https://ideone.com/Bt34BU ... `int string_length(char *string) { return snprintf(0, 0, "%s", string); }`

Answer (score 0):

All the strings in C end with a special char `\0` so you just need to check how many chars there are before that char.

```
int string_length(char *string) {
   int chars = 0;
   while(*string != '\0'){
       chars++;
       string++;
   }
   return chars;
}
```

Comment: no problem, mark this as answer in order to close the question, also, consider to give an upvote on each answer that helps you on SO (when you will have enough reputation)

Comment: @Liam, he did your homework assignement! At least upvote him!

Comment: Nope, just close the question with the tick ahahah